# How to get multiple datepickers to work with altFields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

In my application I have a form for `invoices` which can have multiple `items`. Each item has a date consisting of an input field (where the user can enter the date in his preferred format) and a hidden field (which gets sent to the database when the form gets submitted). Each items gets added to the invoice dynamically with jQuery.

```
<div class="item">
  <input class="display_date" id="display_date_1" type="text" value="15.08.2014">
  <input class="real_date" id="real_date_1" type="text" value="2014-08-15">
  ...
</div>

<div class="item">
  <input class="display_date" id="display_date_2" type="text" value="16.08.2014">
  <input class="real_date" id="real_date_2" type="text" value="2014-08-16">
  ...
</div>

<div class="item">
  <input class="display_date" id="display_date_3" type="text" value="17.08.2014">
  <input class="real_date" id="real_date_3" type="text" value="2014-08-17">
  ...
</div>
```

My question is: How can I get the [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to work on all these (dynamically added) items?

This is my jQuery but it doesn't work:

```
$(function() {

  $('.display_date').each(function(){

    $(this).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd M yy", // format shown to the user
        altField: "#" + $(this).attr('id'),
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd" // format for database processing
      });
    });

});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could give them all the same class, then just call the class in the datepicker.

Comment: That's not working because I am adding items dynamically through jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/d276q92t/1/) with three dynamically created input fields, all linked to datepicker commands. Seems to work.

JS

```
$('.holder').append("<input class='display_date' id='testinput1' type='text' /><input class='display_date' id='testinput2' type='text' /><input class='display_date' id='testinput3' type='text' />");

var mydatepicker = $('#testinput1, #testinput2, #testinput3').datepicker();

$('input').on('click', function(){
                                  var myinput = $(this).attr('id');
                                  $('#'+myinput).datepicker('show');
                                  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to specify the target ID as the alt field.

Try this:

```
<div class="item">
  <input class="display_date" data-target-id="real_date_1" type="text" value="15.08.2014">
  <input class="real_date" id="real_date_1" type="text" value="2014-08-15">
  ...
</div>

<div class="item">
  <input class="display_date" data-target-id="real_date_2" type="text" value="16.08.2014">
  <input class="real_date" id="real_date_2" type="text" value="2014-08-16">
  ...
</div>

<div class="item">
  <input class="display_date" data-target-id="real_date_3" type="text" value="17.08.2014">
  <input class="real_date" id="real_date_3" type="text" value="2014-08-17">
  ...
</div>
```

with:

```
$(function() {

  $('.display_date').each(function(){

    $(this).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd M yy", // format shown to the user
        altField: "#" + $(this).data('target-id'),
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd" // format for database processing
      });
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks but what's the difference between using a data attribute and using the id?

Comment: My data attribute contains the ID of the altField. You can't use IDs twice so I make it a data attribute to store the other elements ID.

Comment: Great solution, the `each` wrapper is the key. Thank you.